# Getting Error after uploading magento full theme pack to server

Tags: magento

Error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'class' (T_CLASS), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$' in vendor\magento\framework\App\Bootstrap.php on line 411

I'm running this on local server on XAMPP on Windows